# How to speed up list appending from dataframe.loc operation

Tags: python, list, dataframe, optimization

I am trying to get the index of first occurance of each unique component names and then appending the indices to the list.

I have dataframe with around 20k rows.

```
 mylist=[]

 for i in df['name']:
        mylist.append(df.loc[df.name==i].index[0])
 mylist=set(mylist)
```

How can I speed up the above process? It takes around a minute to append to the list from dataframe.

Comment: Elgün, please add a screenshot of your `df`

Comment: Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks @YasharAhmadov: Screenshot is only second best solution, text/code would be much better

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve here. It looks a lot like if you're just extracting first level of index grouped by name - which should be a one-liner in pandas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I am trying to get the index of first occurance for each unique name in dataframe

Comment: @YasharAhmadov i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test without a data example, but here it is:

```
df.reset_index().groupby('name').first()['index'].to_list()
```

A minimal reproducible example would look like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'name': ['ABBA', 'LZ', 'LZ', 'LZ', 'IronMaiden', 'PinkFloyd', 'LZ', 'PinkFloyd']})
```

DataFrame:

```
         name
0        ABBA
1          LZ
2          LZ
3          LZ
4  IronMaiden
5   PinkFloyd
6          LZ
7   PinkFloyd
```

Desired outcome:

```
[0, 1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: added a picture

Comment: @ElgunValiyev please add text or code instead

Comment: your code gives the list for the names of unique components rather than their index.

Comment: @ElgunValiyev right. This is why a test example is needed

Comment: this loads from csv file thats why i cant provide here

Comment: @ElgunValiyev that'd not be helpful at all. A good practice is to post a minimal reproducible example, a small made-up dataframe and the desired result

Comment: you are right. basicly I want to get the indices of first occurances for each name from original dataframe. even if as_index=False is set inside groupby it gives the indices from newly created groupby dataframe as 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 etc.

Comment: @ElgunValiyev updated the answer, added what a minimal reproducible example should look like. Note - it's your responsibility to add something like this to the question

Comment: thanks it works as desired.